# Analyze touching particles with holes in a microscopic image

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for an easy method to count individual particles in a microscopic image. It is quite difficult for Mathematica to detect them, because they are touching each other.
I am quite a beginner in Mathematica and can't figure out how I can remove the white centers of the particles. I know there are some similar questions around, but non where the particles have bright centers AND are touching each other.

This is the image:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try this blog post: http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/

Comment: That is what I did first. But my image is too crowded with particles. Too many background spaces are clustered together and I just get a very big particle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest thing that can work is to search *white* blobs instead of black blobs, and ignore the ones that have low circularity (calculated from the area/perimeter^2 ratio):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaMAg.jpg"]
img = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
components = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
   MorphologicalBinarize[Closing[img, DiskMatrix[5]]], {"Centroid", 
    "Circularity", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}, #2 > 0.75 &];

Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle @@@ components[[All, 2, {1, 3}]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: At first glance I thought you were the original poster. Odd coincidence of monikers there. (And a nice answer to a nice question, both of which get votes from me.)

Answer (score 2):

Preprocess like this:

```
ClusteringComponents[
  Erosion[Binarize[mySpheres, {.5, .98}], DiskMatrix[1]]] // Colorize
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help in my case. Maybe my question was unclear. I would like to get a binarizes image where the particles are black (also the centers) and the background is white. From there, I think I know what to do, but I just can't get the particles to be all filled black.

Comment: Oh.... then just use `ColorNegate[]`.

Comment: But then my particles are not their original size, but smaller!?

Comment: So what?  You're counting them.

Comment: Yes, but I want to determine the equivalent sphere diameter in the end and sphericity and so on ... of the original particle size